# How to uploading resize image file by using jquery $.ajax to Parse server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, upload

```
$('#imageSelect').bind("change", function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    file = this.files[0];
    var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + file.name;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
        },
        url: serverUrl,
        data: file,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("File available at: " + data.url);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.error);
        }
    };
```

Above code is working fine If I directly upload a file without other process of file.
But What if I want to upload a image which I have been resized using the same way?

```
.......
resizeImage.src = resize(sourceImage).src
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
        },
        url: serverUrl,
        data: resizeImage,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("File available at: " + data.url);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.error);
        }
    };
```

I got this broken link of the image Url even I had success upload the resizeImage to Server.Please help, thanks.